# Why does Behaviour Flow of Google Analytics show 100% drop off

Tags: google-analytics

I am confused about what I am seeing in the Behaviour Flow of Google Analytics. As you can see from the image below it would appear that after the initial landing page everyone is dropping off. Due to the nature of the application I know that not to be the case.

I have checked that the analytics code is on every page and it is. I'm not sure what else to check. Any suggestions?

[image: Behaviour Flow of Google Analytics]

Comment: I'm sure it has something to do with the page being "(not set)".   I get that in my behavior flow reports too, and I'm not sure why.  That report has always been a bit of mystery to me.

Comment: How are the pages grouped on this page? There's a dropdown at the top left of the report which might be responsible - is it using 'Automatically Grouped Pages'?

Comment: @RhysMills it was actually set to "Flow Grouping Login" but when I changed it to "Automatically Grouped Pages" it all magically appeared! Thanks

Comment: Good stuff - In that case I'll leave an answer to wrap this up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are the pages grouped on this page? There's a dropdown at the top left of the report which might be responsible for this - try setting it to 'Automatically Grouped Pages'